# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dream.category_course' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-7

I am getting this error in saving a many-to many relation in laravel eloquent.
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dream.category_course' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `category_course` (`category_id`, `course_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) values (5, 6, 2020-07-05 07:48:06, 2020-07-05 07:48:06))

but the table **'category_course'** exists in the database dream..

Here is my category model...

```
class Category extends Model
{
protected $table = 'categories';
protected $guarded = [];

public function Course()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class)->using(Category_Course::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```

and this my course model

```
class Course extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'courses';
    protected $guarded = [];
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class)->using(Category_Course::class)->withTimestamps();
}
public function course_content()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Course_Content::class);
}
```

and the customize pivot table

```
    class CreateCategoryCourseTable extends Migration
    {
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('category__course', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('course_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

and here is the controller

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'category_id' => 'required',
            'title' => 'required|max:20|min:10',
            'description' => 'required|min:30|max:100',
            'fee' => 'required|integer|min:1500',
            'duration' => 'required|integer|between:1,12'
        ]);
        $category_id = $data['category_id'];
        unset($data['category_id']);
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $course = \App\user::find($user_id)->course()->create($data);
        $course->category()->attach($category_id);
        return back();
    }
```

I tried everything.I got but still getting this error....
Anyone have any idea..... please

Comment: a) your create uses 2 underscores (`category__course`) b) how did you confirm that the table exists? did you check your database or in your model?

Comment: thanks for the reply.... let me check it.....

Comment: thanks for the quick response. yes, you were right. The problem was the 2 underscores.            problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Two underscores in table name

```
Schema::create('category__course', function (Blueprint $table)
```